# Code to set MyButton with pure code, XML is This

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="-15sp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:paddingTop="32sp"
    android:text="this is text"
    android:textColor="@color/Black" >
</Button>
```

This is the Code I have for my XML, I have been having trouble dynamically creating this, I just need to know what the code for this would look like to create this button. Thanks in advance.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setLayoutParams(params);
            btn.setPadding(0, 32, 0, 0);
            btn.setText("MyButton");
            btn.setTextColor(color.Green);
            Drawable image = Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/ic_launcher"); //
            // btn.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
            btn.setCompoundDrawables(null, image, null, null);
            btn.setCompoundDrawablePadding(15);
            // btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

            ObjectLayout.addView(btn);
        }
```

This is what I had, had, but still not the same Not sure why i can't get it to fill the same.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you possibly show us examples? Not really understanding your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set the background padding for the `Drawable` on the `Drawable` itself, if you want padding on the `Drawable`.

And the `setPadding(...)` uses pixels instead of `sp`.

```
    Button myButton = new Button(/* your context, probably "this" */);
    myButton.setLayoutParams(
            new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myButton.setPadding(0, 32, 0, 0);
    myButton.setText("this is a test");
    myButton.setTextColor(android.R.color.black);
    myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.id.ic_launcher);
```